# Oracle SQL List Intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, list, datetime

I need to create new interval rows based on a start datetime column and an end datetime column.

My statement looks like this currently

```
select id,
startdatetime,
enddatetime
from calls
```

result looks like this

```
id       startdatetime                    enddatetime
1        01/01/2020 00:00:00              01/01/2020 04:00:00
```

I would like a result like this

```
id       startdatetime                    enddatetime                  Intervals
1        01/01/2020 00:00:00              01/01/2020 03:00:00          01/01/2020 00:00:00
1        01/01/2020 00:00:00              01/01/2020 03:00:00          01/01/2020 01:00:00
1        01/01/2020 00:00:00              01/01/2020 03:00:00          01/01/2020 02:00:00
1        01/01/2020 00:00:00              01/01/2020 03:00:00          01/01/2020 03:00:00
```

Thanking you in advance 
p.s. I'm new to SQL

Comment: And why do you get four identical rows?  And where does `03:00:00` come from?

Comment: This should be the result, the added hourly intervals produce duplicates, which i want to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to loop and incrementally add an hour:

```sql
WITH times ( id, startdatetime, enddatetime, intervals ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         startdatetime,
         enddatetime,
         startdatetime
  FROM   calls c
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         startdatetime,
         enddatetime,
         intervals + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
  FROM   times
  WHERE  intervals + INTERVAL '1' HOUR <= enddatetime
)
SELECT *
FROM   times;
```

outputs:

> ```
> ID | STARTDATETIME       | ENDDATETIME         | INTERVALS          
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 2020-01-01 01:00:00
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 2020-01-01 02:00:00
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 2020-01-01 03:00:00
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cbf280f464b0010ae97a8eaae7176468)*

Comment: Hi MT0 I have sense checked and it works, just need to build into my statement now. Thanks fr your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hierarchy` query as following:

> ```
> SQL> WITH CALLS (ID, STARTDATETIME, ENDDATETIME)
>   2  AS ( SELECT 1,
>   3          TO_DATE('01/01/2020 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss'),
>   4          TO_DATE('01/01/2020 04:00:00', 'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss')
>   5      FROM DUAL)
>   6  -- Your query starts from here
>   7  SELECT
>   8      ID,
>   9      STARTDATETIME,
>  10      ENDDATETIME,
>  11      STARTDATETIME + ( COLUMN_VALUE / 24 ) AS INTERVALS
>  12  FROM
>  13      CALLS C
>  14      CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
>  15          SELECT LEVEL - 1
>  16          FROM DUAL
>  17          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(24 *(ENDDATETIME - STARTDATETIME))
>  18      ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) )
>  19  ORDER BY INTERVALS;
>
>         ID STARTDATETIME       ENDDATETIME         INTERVALS
> ---------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
>          1 01/01/2020 00:00:00 01/01/2020 04:00:00 01/01/2020 00:00:00
>          1 01/01/2020 00:00:00 01/01/2020 04:00:00 01/01/2020 01:00:00
>          1 01/01/2020 00:00:00 01/01/2020 04:00:00 01/01/2020 02:00:00
>          1 01/01/2020 00:00:00 01/01/2020 04:00:00 01/01/2020 03:00:00
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Tejash

Thanks for getting back to me. My statement joins many tables together, and has more columns than I showed in my previous request.  

When I'm entering the Table Name after WITH in the first line do I use the Table that I used after the FROM function, even though the ID and start and end times come from Joined tables?

Also, Does Cross Join Table part come after my WHERE function? 

I apologize for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Here is my Statement, it works, I just need to add a column called intervals. The intervals are Between "GMT Start of Period" and "GMT Shift End" and a new line for each Interval. Each line starts with an hour later from the  "GMT Start of Period" column. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XmMNGuxv_5S26iFKvaXgev8o4-0PqvdC  
I could do it in Power BI MQuery with this statement   List.DateTimes([Start of Period], Duration.Hours([Shift End Time] - [Start of Period]) + 1, #duration(0,1,0,0)))  But I need something similar in SQL Thank you